# Civilization 6: hard to see enemy units when at war! How to solve?

Tags: civilization-6

I am playing Civ6, but I have real trouble finding my own units and seeing where the enemy is. This hampers gameplay quite a bit! Take for example this game. Can you find my enemies? It's like "where's Wally"!

[image]

Compare this with Civ5, especially the Strategic View with Icon Mode set on Units. I love this view when at war. The icons of the units are clearly visible and I would never miss an enemy.
[image]
QUESTION: Is a similar setting also possible in Civ6? How do other people use the interface of Civ6 when at war? How to keep track of enemy units?

Comment: Do you need to zoom out all the way, or is zooming in to a level where you can actually see the units an option?

Comment: it might be easier if you didn't use strategic view

Answer (score 1):

With the [Concise UI - Less Icon](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1619941282) mod you can hide icon resources and city banners.